# VB.NET - Open a web application without a user? Render a webpage WITHOUT using the web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, pdf-generation

I have created a web application that builds PDF Forms with data from a SQL DB in a browser. I use a standard letterhead in the form of a JPG as the background image and then use css to position the form elements on the page. Once the DOM is loaded, I make a web service call based on a few parameters and a security key generated when the user logs in to a VB.NET web service. I take the JSON response and populate the form with the information retrieved from the database. Once the form is populated I then pack up the pages HTML, put it in a JSON object and send it to another web service which saves the newly generated PDF to the server using ABCPDF (websupergoo). My client now wants the PDF to save the form without loading it in a browser.

How can I open the web page and have it run through all of its JS functions render completely on the server without any user having to open it in a web browser?

Essentially, what I need to have happen is... a web browser opens on the server... renders the DOM... initiates the web services... Then, on a success response from the last web service... close the web browser on the server...

Is this even possible?

If yes, can someone please share a code block or link to a tutorial on how to get it done?

Comment: You probably don't need to run a browser on the server. Servers communicating is just HTML/CSS/JS/JSON etc. Just make the same requests and responses using typical HTTP client libraries in .NET.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Just look up how to make HTTP requests in .NET. Do a bit of research.

Comment: So just Dim request as WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com/") and BOOM it's done?

Comment: Pretty much - the only difference is you'll be using VB.NET instead of JS to coordinate everything. Browsers are pretty heavyweight, it's best to avoid launching a browser on the server and instead accomplish with lower level HTTP calls.

Comment: I tried that all that does is create a webRequest Class. How do I actually get it to render the web page?

Comment: You don't need to render the page. You're dealing with HTML/CSS/JS/JSON. You don't need an UI. If you need a basic tutorial on how WebRequest works, then look on the web. There's plenty of examples. If you get stuck with your specific implementation, then make a new question, provide your code, and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133665/discussion-between-erik-grosskurth-and-mason).